# Parametrization of orthogonal group

Tags: linear-algebra

For example, take the orthogonal group
$$
O(2) = 
\Big\{ \begin{bmatrix}a & b\\c & d\end{bmatrix} : a^2+b^2=c^2+d^2=1,\ ac+bd=0 \Big\}.
$$
How would you get parametrization of this? I know the answers,  and it's obvious by inspection, but how would you know that $d=-a, c=b$ and $d=a, c=-b$ are the only two solutions?

Comment: Solving *what*? Finding all the solutions as functions of one or several parameters?

Comment: Sorry, as a function of 2 parameters.

Comment: How many restrictions have you?

Comment: 2 I would think.

Comment: Count another time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the conditions $a^2 + b^2 = 1$ and $c^2 + d^2 = 1$, it is natural to put $a = \sin x$, $b = \cos x$, $c = \sin y$, and $d = \cos y$. Substitute these to the last condition $ac + bd = 0$, we get $\sin x \sin y + \cos x \cos y = 0$.

A bit of trigonometry tells you $\cos(x - y) = 0$, which forces $x - y \equiv \pm \pi/2 \pmod{2\pi}$. This shows the required parametrizations.

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was looking for.